# jQuery automatically selects option in select box. How to disable?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm building a website in Wordpress and I have a couple of selectboxes that is used for navigation between different posts. Pretty basic stuff:

```
<select id="all" name="allPostsAllSelect">
<option value="-1" style="font-weight:bold">--All programmes--</option>
<option value="http://site.domain/articleid/">Article 1</option>
...
</select>
```

When an item is selected the current page is loaded and here my problems begin. Somehow the selected option remains selected on the article page, and I am not using frames ;)

I have tried to set breakpoints in firebug and it seems that jquery somewhere in it's over optimized totally unreadable code "helps" me to magically select the option that matches the current URL. I have tried to google this but I can't find anything.

Seems that wordpress uses

```
jquery.js?ver=1.7.2
jquery.cycle.all.js?ver=3.4
jquery.metadata.v2.js?ver=3.4
jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js?ver=3.4
```

Needless to say I do not want this "help", I want the first item to always be selected unless i say something different. What the hell is going on and how can I turn it off?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery, strictly speaking, isn't doing this. The jQuery library does pretty much nothing. Nor am I aware of anything in WordPress that would do this automatically, and WordPress doesn't load any of those scripts on the front end by default (about 90% sure). Something in your theme or a plugin is doing this. Try to figure out which one by disabling your plugins one by one and switching to a default theme. It would be easier if I could see your site. Do you have a public URL?

Comment: Thank you, yup, you can try it here: http://svtsales.com/programme-sales/ select a program to the left and you get what I mean.

Comment: And I am coding pretty much everything self since I do not like the plugin system in wp. So its probably my fault but I can't find it.

Comment: It is one of the "responsive-*" scripts loaded by your theme-- this one, I think: http://svtsales.com/wp-content/themes/responsive/js/responsive-scripts.js?ver=1.1.1

Comment: Great, thank you! That shit is not even readable. Will have to contact the theme creators then. What debugging environment are you using?

Comment: Is it some kind of standard to write java script that looks like shit and is not even readable? Is this what web developers call "optimizing" or are they just trying to protect their Source code? ;)

Comment: Off topic, but that is "minimized" code. It is done to decrease page load time, not to protect the code. It can be 'reversed' pretty easily. Minizing can make a big difference, depending on the size of the script. Look at http://svtsales.com/wp-content/themes/responsive/js-dev/responsive-scripts.js for the working version.

Comment: Ah great thanks, I'll stop the ranting and read up on this! Many thanks all!

Comment: Ok, so I have identified that it is the $('option[value="'+document.location+'"]').attr("selected","selected"); that creates the problem. It seems to reside in some kind of anonymous function and I do not understand when it is called. My inline javascript should be executed after the responsive but it's not so I guess I have to hook on some later event. I don't want to change the responsive script.

Comment: I suspected that function. :) Where is your inline script? Honestly, though, why not just comment that line out of the script? That seems the easiest and most efficient. Does doing that break something else?

Comment: Yes it breaks other functinality. But I think I solved it now, my inline script was executed before the responsive script, so now it's overridden by jQuery("#allPostsAll select").val(1); Thank you all for feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the selected value yourself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // select a specific option
  $("#all").val("-1");
});
```

Or to clear the selected option (will select first by default):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#all").val("");
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, problem is that the jQuery operations is executed after my code somehow. I am unsure how to change this order, maybe I have to hook onto another event than document.ready?

Comment: No, but rather than hacking I would prefer to understand what is going on, and I find it really hard to debug JavaScript even though I use firebug. I really miss a decent environment to work in.